# android.util.Pair holds String[] as parameters in androidTest but null in (unit) test

Tags: java, android, generics, android-testing, android-espresso

I want to unit test a UtilsClass-type static method, that returns a `Pair<String[], String[]>` . Inside this method I inject a pair of String[] into its constructor, eg. `final Pair<String[], String[]> pair = new Pair<>(new String[] {"Hello", "World"}, new String[] {"£33", "£44"});` and expect this object to be returned.

When I unit test this method, I get a non-null Pair object but with its fields `first = null` and `second = null`. When I run the same test code in a Instrumentation-type test, the fields are populated properly. I can see that in the latter case, the constructor `public Pair(F first, S second) {` where I place the debug point is entered and fields set, but not in Unit test.

I am looking for explanation why this would be the case, and if I should avoid passing the `String[]` as constructor params in the code in first place.

Comment: unit test can use mock objects that are basically no-ops. When debugging, you can step into the constructor and see what actually happens. It is possible that the constructor of the class that is used there is actually empty

Comment: This seems to be the case! When I used the convenience method `public static <A, B> Pair <A, B> create(A a, B b) {` instead I got the ""Method ... not mocked."" error. Turning real values in test removed the error, but values in both creation methods were still null.

android.support.v4.util.Pair doesn't suffer from this at all.

Comment: Yes, because support being library, it is bundled with your apk anyway (so it can't be mocked by the unit testing)

Comment: If you provide this as the answer, I will accept it. thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As njk2 and TomaszRykala discovered, using android.support.v4.util.Pair instead of android.util.Pair fixes this issue.